# How to fill the space exactly the screen width or height in the image breaking puzzle game in android

Tags: android, gridview

Here am developed a puzzle game, image tiles place in gridview, but the thing is, I would like to fill complete device screen width or device screen height with those tiles.
Here is my result.[image]

Here is my code, please tell me where am doing mistake.

```
public class ImageBreaking_Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button b_save, view_bb;
    private Bitmap b;
    int position;
    ImageButton b_90, b_360;
    GridView grid;
    String filePath,biks;
    Bitmap selectedphoto_bitmap;
    int row, col, val;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> imageChunks = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> imageChunks_child = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> duplicate_bitmaps, duplicate_bitmaps_dump;
    public ArrayList<MyBitamp> itemList_dump = new ArrayList<MyBitamp>();
    public ArrayList<MyBitamp> itemList_dump__c = new ArrayList<MyBitamp>();
    View v_duplicate;
    private int count;
    ImageAdapter__c adapter;
    boolean clicked = false;
    private int touchedItemPos = 0;
    private MyBitamp tile;
    AlertDialog.Builder ad;
    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    private int Screenwidth;
    private int Screenheight;
    int gameScreen_width,gameScreen_height;
    private int width_bitmap;
    private int height_bitmap;
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_breaking_);
        // screen width x Height





        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        b_90 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        b_90.setOnClickListener(this);
        view_bb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        view_bb.setOnClickListener(this);
        b_360 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        b_360.setOnClickListener(this);

        // side vices

        filePath = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("File_path");
        biks = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("File_path_biks");
        Log.i("W x H", "biks:" + biks);

        selectedphoto_bitmap = decodeFile(filePath);

        Log.i("Bitmap Width x Height", selectedphoto_bitmap.getWidth()+"& &"+selectedphoto_bitmap.getHeight());
        // bitmap width x height

        width_bitmap=selectedphoto_bitmap.getWidth();
        height_bitmap=selectedphoto_bitmap.getHeight();





        if(selectedphoto_bitmap.getWidth()>selectedphoto_bitmap.getHeight()){


            val = selectedphoto_bitmap.getWidth()%selectedphoto_bitmap.getHeight();
            // showing if bitmap width is higher than bitmap height, then rotating to 90 degrees 
             Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
             matrix.postRotate(90);
             selectedphoto_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(selectedphoto_bitmap, 0, 0, 
                     selectedphoto_bitmap.getWidth(), selectedphoto_bitmap.getHeight(), 
                     matrix, true);

        }else{

                 val=selectedphoto_bitmap.getHeight()%selectedphoto_bitmap.getWidth();


            }


        // for rows and cols
         col=selectedphoto_bitmap.getWidth()/val;
         row=selectedphoto_bitmap.getHeight()/val;











    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        break_up(selectedphoto_bitmap);
        super.onStart();
    }

    private void break_up(Bitmap selectedphoto_bitmap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int chunkHeight, chunkWidth,A;

        imageChunks = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(col * row);// size of array let us go for 12 or 16



        // for perfect square tile
        chunkHeight = selectedphoto_bitmap.getHeight() / row;// setting height for tile
        chunkWidth = selectedphoto_bitmap.getWidth() / col;// setting width for tile





        Log.i("Main Activity_chuck bitmap", chunkHeight
                + " <--chunk__h & chunk__w-->" + chunkWidth);

        Log.i("Main Activity_bitmap row and col", col + ":cols & Rows:" + row);

        int yCoord = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) { 
            int xCoord = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {

                // adding those tile to the array

                        imageChunks.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(selectedphoto_bitmap,
                        xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
                xCoord += chunkWidth;

                Log.i("Array bitmap", "" + imageChunks.get(y).getWidth()
                        + "<-- w & H-->" + imageChunks.get(y).getHeight());
            }
            yCoord += chunkHeight;
        }

        Log.i("TAG", "no of size" + imageChunks);
        Log.i("TAG", "no of size" + imageChunks.size());

    }

    private Bitmap decodeFile(String f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale++;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub







        for (int i = 0, j = imageChunks.size(); i < j; i++) {


            // taken one model class and passing width,height, id, item_position, rotation
            MyBitamp item_dump = new MyBitamp(imageChunks.get(i)
                    .getWidth(), imageChunks.get(i).getHeight(),

                    imageChunks.get(i), i, i, 0);

            itemList_dump.add(item_dump);

        }


        Collections.shuffle(itemList_dump);// shuffling the items
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();// random number for rotation
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(4);

        for (int i = 0, j = itemList_dump.size(); i < j; i++) {
            itemList_dump.get(i).setItemCurPos(i);// set the item current position
            itemList_dump.get(i).setrotation(randomInt);// set the rotation

        }
        adapter = new ImageAdapter__c(this);// custom adapter
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setNumColumns(col);

        grid.setColumnWidth(imageChunks.get(0).getWidth());
        grid.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on save", 1).show();
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton1:

            /* rotate view */
            tile = itemList_dump.get(touchedItemPos);

            if (b_90.isEnabled() && clicked) {

                int fix_rotation = tile.getrotation();

                if (fix_rotation != 0) {

                    if (fix_rotation == 0) {
                        fix_rotation = 0;
                        tile.setrotation(fix_rotation);

                    } else {

                        if (fix_rotation == 2) {

                            tile.setrotation(3);

                        } else

                        if (fix_rotation == 1) {

                            tile.setrotation(2);

                        } else if (fix_rotation == 3) {

                            tile.setrotation(0);

                        }

                    }
                } else {

                    tile.setrotation(1);
                    // itemList_dump.get(position).setrotation(1);
                }
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(ImageBreaking_Activity.this,
                        "select the item to rotate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

        case R.id.imageButton2:

            if (b_360.isEnabled() && clicked) {
                tile = itemList_dump.get(touchedItemPos);
                int fix_rotation__c = (int) tile.getrotation();

                if (fix_rotation__c != 0) {

                    if (fix_rotation__c == 1) {

                        tile.setrotation(0);

                    } else if (fix_rotation__c == 2) {

                        tile.setrotation(1);

                    } else if (fix_rotation__c == 3) {

                        tile.setrotation(2);

                    }
                } else {

                    tile.setrotation(3);

                }
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(ImageBreaking_Activity.this,
                        "Select item to Rotate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

        case R.id.button2:

            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_xml);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setImageBitmap(selectedphoto_bitmap);
            d.show();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    public class ImageAdapter__c extends BaseAdapter implements
            OnTouchListener, OnDragListener {

        Context context;
        int coordinates[] = new int[2];
        ArrayList<MyBitamp> item_list_data = new ArrayList<MyBitamp>();
        ArrayList<Bitmap> duplicate = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        Bitmap b;
        HashMap<View, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<View, Integer>();
        // ArrayList<MyBitamp> item_list_data_mybit = new ArrayList<MyBitamp>();
        int i = 0, temp, temp2, count = 0, mod, position;
        private int dest;
        private int source;
        private ImageView img;
        private Integer touchedItemPosition;
        private Integer dropedItemPosition;
        private MyBitamp Data;

        public ImageAdapter__c(ImageBreaking_Activity context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return itemList_dump.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return itemList_dump.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            img = new ImageView(context);

            Data = itemList_dump.get(pos);
            Data.setItemCurPos(pos);

            img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(itemList_dump
                    .get(pos).getWidth(), itemList_dump.get(pos).getHeight()));

            img.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
            img.setImageBitmap(itemList_dump.get(pos).getImageRes());

            // rotation
            int r_tation__C = itemList_dump.get(pos).getrotation();

            if (r_tation__C == 0) {

                img.setRotation(0);
            } else if (r_tation__C == 1) {

                img.setRotation(90);

            } else if (r_tation__C == 2) {

                img.setRotation(180);
            } else if (r_tation__C == 3) {

                img.setRotation(270);
            }

            else {
                img.setRotation(360);

            }
            img.setOnTouchListener(this);

            img.setOnDragListener(this);
            hashMap.put(img, pos);

            if (check_result()) {

                Toast.makeText(ImageBreaking_Activity.this, "Success",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageBreaking_Activity.this);
                ad.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                Intent i_home = new Intent(
                                        ImageBreaking_Activity.this,
                                        HomePage.class);

                                i_home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                                startActivity(i_home);
                                ImageBreaking_Activity.this.finish();
                            }
                        });
                ad.setMessage("Congratulations....!");
                ad.setCancelable(false);

                ad.show();

            }


            // more work//




            return img;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v_duplicate = v;
            clicked = true;

            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (hashMap.containsKey(v)) {
                    touchedItemPosition = hashMap.get(v);
                    touchedItemPos = touchedItemPosition;
                    MyBitamp bitamp = itemList_dump.get(touchedItemPos);
                    // Toast.makeText(context,
                    // "current pos:"+bitamp.getItemCurPos()+"original pos"+bitamp.getItemPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                    // item_list_data.get(touchedItemPosition);
                }

                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                return true;
            } else

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return false;
            }

            else

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                return false;
            }

            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            }
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            dropedItemPosition = hashMap.get(v);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                // do nothing
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                swapItemPositions(dropedItemPosition, touchedItemPosition);

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:


                Log.i("Drop", "end");

            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        void swapItemPositions(int current, int target) {

            MyBitamp tempBitmap = itemList_dump.get(current);
            itemList_dump.set(current, itemList_dump.get(target));
            itemList_dump.set(target, tempBitmap);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private boolean check_result() {

            boolean isCompleted = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < itemList_dump.size(); i++) {

                int posit_fix = itemList_dump.get(i).getItemPosition();

                int posit_current = itemList_dump.get(i).getItemCurPos();
                int rotation = itemList_dump.get(i).getrotation();

                if (((posit_fix == posit_current) && rotation == 0)) {
                    isCompleted = true;

                } else {
                    isCompleted = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (isCompleted) {
                // success

            } else {
                // failure
            }
            return isCompleted;

        }
    }

}
```

My xml file,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#223344" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    </GridView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SAVE" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:src="@drawable/plus_90" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:src="@drawable/minus_90" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="VIEW" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Provide solution, Thank you

Comment: `Gridview` width you should use `fill_parent` or `match_parent` and remove align_parent_right

Comment: Actually Am cutting the tile dynamically with perfect square shape. imaging bitmap width x height is 320 x 240 for that we have 3 rows and 4 col's, so each bitmap tile size is 80 x 80, but the device screen size is 800 x 1232, filling with the bitmap dimensions, a gap is coming, so how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Gridview` width as fill_parent or match_parent. Currently you are using `wrap_content` which gives the grid only the space contained by your `ImageView`. Thats why you are getting the gap

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    >

</GridView>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this grid view

```
 <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"
         android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

change your gridview like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#223344" >

 <GridView
android:id="@+id/grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
>

</GridView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="SAVE" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_90" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:src="@drawable/minus_90" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="VIEW" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```